# Enable warning message when null response selected (ActionScript 3)

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to create a situation where the user has to select a response in order to proceed to another query. I was able to make the program display a warning message when the response to the FIRST question is not answered. Once a person answers the first question, their response is deselected, a second question is presented, and they are to select a response for the second question. However, it seems that for the subsequent questions, the person need not select a response in order to continue. That is, if they do NOT select a response for these questions, they are nevertheless allowed to proceed. Furthermore, this is the error I received in the output: TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

Thanks for your attention.

```
var responseData:String = new String;


lstResponses.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, responseSelected);
btnContinue.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickWarning);

function clickWarning(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
txtWarning.text = "Please select a response";
}

function responseSelected(evt:Event):void
{
txtWarning.visible = false;
btnContinue.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickWarning);
btnContinue.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, continueClicked);
}

function continueClicked(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
responseData = lstResponses.selectedItem.data;
lstResponses.selectedItem = null;
trace(responseData);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the selected item is null and refuse to continue until it isn't. With this check in place you should only need 1 function to handle your results.

```
btnContinue.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, continueClicked);
function continueClicked(evt:MouseEvent):void{
    if(lstResponses.selectedItem==null){
        txtWarning.text = "Please select a response";
    }else{
        responseData = lstResponses.selectedItem.data;
        lstResponses.selectedItem = null;
        trace(responseData);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply; however, it seems that the warning message isn't displaying when one clicks continue without having selecting a response. Instead, I'm getting this message in the output:

TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

Comment: Pardon me. I left out a tiny bit. I meant `lstResponses.selectedItem==null` as opposed to `lstResponses==null`. Try that instead.